Font Family doesn't work in my nextJs project
This is my layout.tsx file
import localFont from "next/font/local";
import { Inter, Roboto, Open_Sans, Poppins } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import Navigation from "./components/Navigation";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";

const inter = Inter({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  weight: ["400", "500", "600", "700"],
  variable: "--font-inter",
});

const openSans = Open_Sans({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  weight: ["400", "500", "600", "700"],
  variable: "--font-openSans",
});

const roboto = Roboto({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  weight: ["100", "300", "400", "500", "700", "900"],
  variable: "--font-roboto",
});
const poppins = Poppins({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  weight: ["100", "300", "400", "500", "600", "700", "900"],
  variable: "--font-poppins",
});

const helvetica = localFont({
  src: "./fonts/Helvetica.ttf",
  variable: "--font-helvetica",
  weight: "100 900",
});

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body
        className={` ${helvetica.variable} ${inter.className} ${roboto.variable} ${openSans.variable} ${poppins.variable} antialiased`}
      >
        <Navigation />
        {children}
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

This is tailwind config file

export default {
  content: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
            fontFamily: {
              inter: ['var(--font-inter)', 'sans-serif'],
              helvetica: "var(--font-helvetica)",
              roboto: "var(--font-roboto)",
              openSans: "var(--font-openSans)",
              poppins: "var(--font-poppins)",
            },
            letterSpacing: {
              'custom-percentage': '0.02em',
            },
            screens: {
              '3xl': '1920px',
              'xs': '440px',
            },
            lineHeight: {
              '110': '1.1',
              '120': '1.2',
              '130': '1.3',
              '150': '1.5',
            },
          },
  },
  plugins: [],
} satisfies Config;

"I'm using Inter as the default font for my page, while other fonts are applied to specific HTML elements. However, when inspecting the page, it shows the system UI font instead of Inter or the specified fonts. I'm not sure why the correct fonts aren't being applied."

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I also did face this issue once, my solution was re-checking and ensuring all font files are correctly placed and paths are accurate.
Also what you can do is:
Update RootLayout to Apply Fonts Properly,
Instead of applying multiple font variables to the <body>, focus on setting the default font and providing CSS variables for additional fonts.
CSS Variables: Apply all font variables to the <html> element. This ensures that CSS variables are available throughout the application.
Default Font: Use className="font-sans antialiased" on the <body> to apply the default sans-serif font (Inter) and antialiasing.
